# Ticking off your down-the-middle explanation

Tags: vocabulary

> **Ticking off your down-the-middle explanation of world news**.I`m Carl
>   Azuz. Thank you for taking 10 for CNN 10.

http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1805/02/sn.01.html

What does the whole sentence mean?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a standard expression, or even a combination of expressions: I suspect that it is an unscripted introduction by Mr Azuz and only he would know exactly what he intended it to mean.

**Ticking off** could refer to checking off a series of items of world news, but it's more likely to be a mis-transcription of **kicking off**, which is a sporting metaphor for starting.

**down-the-middle** could suggest that it is an impartial presentation, but more likely it is intended to suggest that the world news will be presented in a concise summary with few diversions (down the middle, rather than taking a roundabout route).